# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > TransformException: ProcessException: ExecException:

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex

I can not build a Android Studio project. I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

MultiDex is enabled in app.gradle:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId 'my.app'
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 4
            versionName "1.1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
...
```

I tried to remove "build" folders, but it didn't give me any result. How I can solve this problem?

**EDIT:** This project builds on other computer (Mac Mini / OS X), but doesn't build's on my computer (Windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to resolve the issue:

Step 1: Add a class named as **MyApplication** and extend it with **MultiDexApplication** class.

Step 2: Declare this **MyApplication** class name in your application tag in manifest.

```
<application

    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Step 3: Override the **attachBaseContext** in the MyApplication class and call Multidex.install() method:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Try running the project with the above changes and it should work!

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons for this error. If the above answer doesnt help then try reviewing your dependencies in build.gradle. You need to check if you are not using two same libraries or you are not using different versions of same library specially that of google play services sub libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the dependencies repeat.Plesae modify this mistake , clean and rebuilt this project.

Comment: I have read your app.gradle. 'proguard-rules.pro' and 'compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])'  may be conflicting.You can add '#' before '-libraryjars libs/.jar' in proguard-rules.pro to have a try.